# Building matrix from relational data

Tags: matrix, data-structures

I'm new to Mathematica, coming from Python, and I'm having a hard time trying to build a matrix from relational data.

The data looks like this:

```
BOB,fr
STEVE,us
STEVE,gb
BOB,us
```

Which once imported look like this:

```
test = Import["test.csv"]

{{"BOB", "fr"}, {"STEVE", "us"}, {"STEVE", "gb"}, {"BOB", "us"}}
```

My aim is to reach this kind of format:

```
       fr   us   gb
BOB    1    1    0
STEVE  0    1    1
```

The only thing I managed to achieve, probably over-complicating (and slowing) the procedure is:

```
Function[y, {y, Counts[Select[test, Function[x, x[[1]] == y]][[All, 2]]]}] /@ deleteDuplicates[test[[All, 1]]] // TableForm
```

Which yields:

```
BOB    <|fr-> 1, us-> 1|>
STEVE  <|fr-> 1, gb-> 1|>
```

Please, what is the obvious thing I'm missing ? Any keyword or way of doing things I could look for ?

Thanks !

Comment: I guess, something like `grp = Counts /@ GroupBy[test, First -> Last];
Dataset[AssociationThread[Keys[grp], KeyUnion[Values[grp], 0 &]]]`?

Comment: I learned quite a lot looking at the doc of every function you used, thanks very much !

Comment: It's a bit clunky, due to the need to decompose and recompose an `Association[]` just to be able to use `KeyUnion[]`. Somebody better than me should be able to come up with something slicker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way based upon `GroupBy`:

```
countTable[list_] :=
  GroupBy[
    KeyUnion[<| "" -> #[[1]], #[[2]] -> 1 |> & /@ list, 0&]
  , #[""]& -> KeyDrop[""]
  , Total
  ]
```

This presumes that there are no empty strings in the source data.  The role played by `""` could be filled equally well by `0`, `Null`, `{}`, a symbol, or any other convenient unused value.

Usage:

```
test = {{"BOB", "fr"}, {"STEVE", "us"}, {"STEVE", "gb"}, {"BOB",  "us"}};

result = countTable[test]

(* <| "BOB"   -> <|"fr" -> 1, "us" -> 1, "gb" -> 0|>
    , "STEVE" -> <|"fr" -> 0, "us" -> 1, "gb" -> 1|>
    |>
*)
```

This representation is convenient for further querying:

```
result["STEVE"]
(* <|"fr" -> 0, "us" -> 1, "gb" -> 1|> *)

result["STEVE", "us"]
(* 1 *)

result[["STEVE", {"fr", "gb"}]]
(* <|"fr" -> 0, "gb" -> 1|> *)
```

We can use `Dataset` to visualize the result:

```
result // Dataset
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

The method accounts for duplicates within the source data:

```
test ~Join~ {{"STEVE", "us"}, {"BOB", "fr"}} // countTable // Dataset
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: Wow! $\phantom{}$

Comment: @J.M. Thanks.  I quite liked your method too.

Comment: @J.M. Funny,why [I cannot "Wow!"](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/04/02/58dfd9d80ba34.jpg)?And can you also "Wow" my answer? :)

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Module[{e = Rule @@@ SortBy[#, { First, Last}], 
   v = DeleteDuplicates /@ Transpose[SortBy[#, {First, Last}]], l}, 
   l = Length /@ v;
   AdjacencyMatrix[Graph[Join @@ v, e]][[;; First@l, 1 + First@l ;;]]] &;

f@test // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
TableForm[Normal@f@test, 
  TableHeadings -> DeleteDuplicates /@ Transpose[SortBy[test, {First, Last}]]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
test2 = Join[test, {{"ALICE", "hu"}, {"BOB", "ua"}}];

TableForm[Normal@f@test2, TableHeadings -> 
  DeleteDuplicates /@ Transpose[SortBy[test2, {First, Last}]]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Also

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2 = Module[{ff, a = DeleteDuplicates /@ Transpose[SortBy[#, {First, Last}]]}, 
    (ff[##] = 1) & @@@ #; ff[__] := 0; Outer[ff, First@a, Last@a]] &;

f2 @ test // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f2 @ test2 // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
list={{"BOB","fr"},{"STEVE","us"},{"STEVE","gb"},{"BOB","us"}};    
pos = Flatten[Position[VertexList[Rule @@@ list], _String?#]] & /@ {UpperCaseQ,LowerCaseQ};
MatrixForm[AdjacencyMatrix[Rule @@@ list][[##]] & @@ pos]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `Merge`:

```
list = {{"BOB", "fr"}, {"STEVE", "us"}, {"STEVE", "gb"}, {"BOB", "us"}};

m = Merge[Apply @ Association] @ ReplaceAll[{a_, b_} :> {a -> {b -> 1}}] @ list
```

<|"BOB" -> <|"fr" -> 1, "us" -> 1|>, "STEVE" -> <|"us" -> 1, "gb" -> 1|>|>

**Method 1**

```
AssociationThread[Keys[m] -> KeyUnion[Values[m], 0 &]] // Dataset
```

[image]

**Method 2**

```
 Query[Transpose] @ m // Dataset
```

[image]

`Query[Transpose]` has automatically inserted the missing values!

Maybe this is the form we want, if not:

```
 Query[Transpose] @  m /. _Missing :> 0 // Query[Transpose] // Dataset
```

(* Output like Method 1 *)